# How to collect errors after call `valid?` method on object?

Tags: ruby, validation

```
class Oauth
  RESPONSE_TYPE       = 'response_type'
  CLIENT_ID           = 'client_id'
  REDIRECT_URI        = 'redirect_uri'
  AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN = 'authorization_token'
  REQUIRED_PARAMS     = [RESPONSE_TYPE, CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI]
  VALID_PARAMS        = REQUIRED_PARAMS

  attr_reader :errors

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
    @errors = []
  end

  def valid?
    REQUIRED_PARAMS.all?{ |param| valid_params.has_key?(param) }
  end

  # private

  def valid_params
    @params.slice(*VALID_PARAMS)
  end
end
```

I would like to collect `missing #{param} key` errors after calling `valid?` method.

Comment: You'd have to be saving in your errors attribute for that (if using rails, consider using ActiveModel::Validations)

Comment: I'm confused.  I presume `@params` is an array but `Array#slice` does not take strings as arguments. (If `@params` were a string--doubtful--same problem.) Could this be a Rail's thing, with `slice` defined on some class I don't know about? The "validation" tag may be meaningful to Rails' people, but not to the unwashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make your OAuth Object an [ActiveModel](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activemodel/4.1.5/frames) it behaves like an ActiveRecord Model but is not backed via DB. ActiveModel allows you to use validations as you would in an AR model, so fetching the validation errors would be likewise.